# How to grep lines having specific format

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep

I have got a file with following format.

```
1234, 'US', 'IN',......
324, 'US', 'IN',......
...
...
53434, 'UK', 'XX', ....
...
...
253, 'IN', 'UP',....
253, 'IN', 'MH',....
```

Here I want to extract only those lines having 'IN' as 2nd keyword. i.e.

```
253, 'IN', 'UP',....
253, 'IN', 'MH',....
```

Can any one please tell me a command to grep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep -E ^[^,]*,\ \'IN\',.+\$ FILENAME

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
egrep "^[0-9]+, 'IN'"
```